# Table Documenting: Query to return basic stats (Min, Max, Count(*), Count(distinct *), etc) for every column in a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working on a project to document the tables in a database. One of the features I would like to include is a meta-table that includes some facts and statistics for every column in the table. I already have a query that does the following:

| Column | Data Type | Nullable | Primary Key | Foreign Key |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Col A | string | N | PK |  |
| Col B | string | N |  | FK |
| Etc..... |  |  |  |  |

I would also like to get some common statistics of each column as either another table (or preferably as part of the above table) that would look like:

| Column | Min | Max | Count | Count Distinct |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Col A | 1 | 486842 | 486842 | 486842 |
| Col B | 1 | 756 | 486842 | 395 |
| Col C | 1 | 5 | 210523 | 3 |

Perhaps also "Most Common Value" and "# of Most Common Value". Basic information that will give me a quick idea as to the distribution and uniqueness of values in a column. The calculations aren't the hard part. I don't understand how to connect actual tables to meta data. It also has a confusing back-and-forth pivot aspect.

Can this be done dynamically without typing out each and every column?

The following query produces the first table:

```
select
       col.name as column_name,
       t.name as data_type,    
        case when col.is_nullable = 0 then 'N' 
             else 'Y' end as nullable,
        case when pk.column_id is not null then 'PK' 
             else '' end as primary_key, 
        case when fk.parent_column_id is not null then 'FK' 
             else '' end as foreign_key
       
   from sys.tables as tab
        left join sys.columns                                                       as col
            on tab.object_id = col.object_id
        left join sys.types                                                         as t
            on col.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
               left join (
                  select index_columns.object_id, 
                         index_columns.column_id
                    from sys.index_columns
                         inner join sys.indexes 
                             on index_columns.object_id = indexes.object_id
                            and index_columns.index_id = indexes.index_id
                   where indexes.is_primary_key = 1
                  )                                                                  as pk 
            on col.object_id = pk.object_id 
           and col.column_id = pk.column_id

        left join (
                  select fc.parent_column_id, 
                         fc.parent_object_id
                    from sys.foreign_keys as f 
                         inner join sys.foreign_key_columns as fc 
                             on f.object_id = fc.constraint_object_id
                   group by fc.parent_column_id, fc.parent_object_id
                  )                                                                  as fk
            on fk.parent_object_id = col.object_id 
           and fk.parent_column_id = col.column_id    
      
where tab.name = 'table_products'
order by primary_key desc, foreign_key desc, nullable asc, column_name asc;
```

Edit: Solved via comments showing that SQL Server Column Statistics already provide this type of information.

Comment: I would ask what purpose does this serve? Storing things like the number of non-`NULL` values in a column is going to become very out of date very quickly, and things like counting the number of `DISTINCT` values in **every** column is *very* expensive.

Comment: On top of what @Larnu said, would like to point out that most of this information is available in SQL Server via index/column statistics (see https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-statistics-and-how-to-perform-update-statistics-in-sql/)

Comment: You'll have to do a but more work, but does this answer your question? [Query Number of Populated Rows for Each Column in Table (SQL Server)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70354528/table-documenting-query-to-return-basic-stats-min-max-count-countdistin?noredirect=1#comment124365870_70354528)

Comment: Yes, they'll all be out of date practically instantly and would have to be flagged with a "last updated" date. The purpose of knowing the number of values that are non-null or distinct is that you can start to form some quick guesses as to what type of results different types of joins will create (many-to-many vs one-to many relationships) or (will a left join have radically different results from an inner join). Also, this would only be for the 20-30 most used columns of the 20-30 most used tables.

Comment: Just use the normal statistics. You can even create multi-column or filtered statistics, and statistics on indexed views

Comment: Look at using APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT if the stats don't meet your needs